# "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'1[WebLabsV04.DAL.Data.ApplicationDbContext]'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a little project for my Uni homework using ASP.NET Core MVC. I needed to create a class library project, where I created my own `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebLabsV04.DAL.Entities;

namespace WebLabsV04.DAL.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DishGroup> DishGroups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Later I had to create a scaffolded item Razor Page using Entity Framework (CRUD) but I always get this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'1[WebLabsV04.DAL.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'WebLabsV04.DAL.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.

I already checked few answers for that question where people recommended registering a service for `ApplicationDbContext`, but it didn't help.

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
using Laba1;
using Laba1.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Configuration;
using WebLabsV04.DAL.Data;
using WebLabsV04.DAL.Entities;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>(); 

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
});

var app = builder.Build();
var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();

var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

DbInitializer.Seed(context, userManager, roleManager)
 .GetAwaiter()
 .GetResult();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to configure the options `DbContextOptions` in your DI setup, which are required in the ApplicationDbContext constructor.

Comment: Why you call the identity service twice? One is Default identity and another is Identity user?

Comment: @marsze like that `builder.Services.AddOptions<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>();`?